# Strange javascript (jQuery) behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple chat that uses ajax to get messages, heres the code:

```js
function get_message_chat() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    url: "chat.php",
    global: true,
    type: "GET",
    data: "event=get&id=" + mid + "&t=" + (new Date).getTime()
  });

  $.ajax({
    success: function(msg_j) {
      if (msg_j.length > 2) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg_j);
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          console.log(msg_j.length);

          if (mid >= obj[i].id) {
            continue;
          }

          mid = obj[i].id;
          name = obj[i].name;
          msg = obj[i].msg
          $("#msg-box ul").append("<li><b><span class=\"username\" >" + name + "</span></b>:<span id=\"msgid_" + mid + "\" class=\"messsage\" style=\"color:black;\" > " + msg + "</span></li>");

          if (msg.indexOf('@' + username) != -1) {
            $("#msgid_" + mid).css('font-weight', 'bold');
          }
        }
        $("#msg-box").scrollTop(2000);
      }
    }
  });
  setTimeout(get_message_chat, 2000);
}

mid = 0;
```

It grabs messages from php script "starts from mid ID". Then it shows messages to chat(appends to ul) and sets mid to new message id and then loop repeats. The problem is that it stucks fter mid = 9 for some reason. I still have more messages coming:

```
[{"id":"10","name":"user1","msg":"messages1234"},
{"id":"11","name":"user2","msg":"messages5678"}]
```

But they wont display. Everyting looks fine, but I can't understand why is that happening. Thank you for all comments.

Comment: what is the use of this `if (mid >= obj[i].id)` condition?

Comment: Because on production host requests are slow and they may be few ajax requests at the same time, so messages will be doubled on display. Thats why i need that check to prevent older messages to show up.

Comment: You are operating with strings here, so `9` is of course _greater than_ `10`. Use parseInt on the values before making the comparison.

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser console (if debugging with for example Chrome)?

Comment: I think this compare method behaveor like string compare. May be the problem solves if you write  if (mid*1 >= obj[i].id*1)

Comment: Thanks to all, int comparsion made it works right!